# Is it possible to connect the adafruit fingerprint sensor to a database?

Tags: c++, arduino, fingerprint

https://www.adafruit.com/products/751

I am trying to implement a patient identification system using the adafruit fingerprint sensor with arduino.

https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-Fingerprint-Sensor-Library

However, it seems that currently all of the fingerprint image/feature was store on the chip inside the fingerprint scanner. Since I will probably store more than 163 fingerprints, I was wondering if I can change the storage.

I can't seem to find anything related to set image or store image in the .cpp, but from the Chinese original manual there is a upimage and downimage.

http://www.adafruit.com/datasheets/DY001fingerprint.pdf

Is it possible for me to store and extract image/features from the chip and store it into database?

Thanks.

Comment: I know nothing about the subject, but I imagine that the problem here is that the fingerprint sensor itself does the recognition. In this case, the image stored inside the sensor itself is key to making that comparison, and you can't choose other images. So if you are trying to simply identify the owner of the hand from the fingerprint, you will need to have all candidates in the sensor. If you have the identity (so you are just trying to ensure the person is who they say they are), you would be able to load that image to the senor before scanning the finger.

Comment: @MatsPetersson you're right. LouisTsai: please read this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fingerprint_recognition How do you want to match user ? current user against a specific user or against all users ?

Comment: I know how fingerprint works, but I don’t know how this particular model work  (or not ).  I know the desktop software can extract fingerprint images  (of about 200 x 200), but I am not sure if I can do that on a arduino,  and I don't know if I can put images back to the device.  I was hoping I could extract images and store them in my custom database in somewhere else,  and throw them back into the scanner in batches.

Comment: I'm trying to do identification, not verification

Comment: So, you will then have to extract the image scanned at the time, and make your own comparison - at least that's how I understand it to work.

Comment: Since the scanner already has dedicated chip (which is pretty fast)  for identifying fingerprint, I was hoping I could use that instead of starting from scratch

Comment: @LouisTsai How do you get the image from the fingerprint sensor?

Answer (score 0):

You can extract image/templates and upload templates to the chip using this library https://github.com/hmxmghl/Modified_AdafruitFingerprintSensor_Library